# Slow Page loading when using ExpanderView & Binding (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, silverlight-toolkit

I have a Panorama control, which has an ExpanderView Item (from Silverlight toolkit).
My client wants this page to be customizable. Thats why I created 3 level of binding:
The PanoramaItems, the ExpanderView headers and the ExpanderView content.
The problem when I set the itemssource of the Panorama control. it takes about 5 seconds to show the items.

Any idea how I can solve this?

C# code:

```
private void panorama_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        this.DataContext = App.Products; 
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<controls:Panorama Loaded="panorama_Loaded" x:Name="panorama" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Sub_Products}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView  Header="{Binding}" Expander="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Sub_Sub_Products}">
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/List.png" Width="25" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </toolkit:ExpanderView.ExpanderTemplate>
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="-30,0,0,0" Background="White"  Width="450" Tap="Grid_Tap" >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="0"  Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                                            <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"  />
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                <TextBlock Margin="0,12,32,0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Learn more" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama>
```

Comment: Show some code.  Also, how much data are you loading (how many panorama items, how many headers, and how much content)?  Guidelines say you should have fewer than 5 pano items for performance reasons.

Comment: I have 4 panorama items, and about 3-6 expanderview headers, each one has 3 expanderview contents. the code is very long, ill try to reduce the lines and share it here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to collapse the panorama items that are off screen and only set visibility to visible on demand. That should at least reduce the size of the visible tree.

A good way to find the slow parts is to use the profiler in Visual Studio. You will find one frame which is really slow (it will have a render time of 5 seconds in your case). Then dig into the visual tree of that frame and see which elements took a long time to render and try to optimize these.

Comment: Hi, I'm not ignoring your answer. I just didnt have time to try it, got involved in another projects. Will give you the points if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ExpanderView ItemsSource binding in xaml and bind to it when the Expander is manupulated in code. Just leave it as `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. That way you will dynamically build you visual tree as the user taps on the expander.

The event handler is something like below. ***I am assuming Product is the type in your App.Products list***. Also ensure that you hook up the event in your xaml for the expander.

```
 private void ExpanderView_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            var expander = sender as ExpanderView;
            expander.ItemsSource = (expander.DataContext as Product).Sub_Sub_Products;
        }
```

Hope this solves your slow loading issues and is not too late at this time.